# Comparison of type theory based on relations vs logic based on functions

Tags: logic, reference-request, type-theory

As it has been mentioned in [Type Theory article at Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/), type theories fall into two classes, one in which functions are not primitive but functional relations which I believe is attributed to Russel, and the other in which functions are primitive (uses $\lambda$-abstraction) and was introduced by church, though in the article it states that the origin goes back to Frege.

> In these versions of type theory, as in set theory, functions are not primitive objects, but are represented as functional relation. The addition function for instance is represented as a ternary relation by an object of type
> (
> i
> ,
> i
> ,
> i
> )
> . An elegant formulation of the simple type theory which extends it by introducing functions as primitive objects was given by Church in 1940. It uses the
> λ
> -calculus notation (Barendregt 1997). Since such a formulation is important in computer science, for the connection with category theory, and for Martin-Löf type theory, we describe it in some detail. In this formulation, predicates are seen as a special kind of functions (propositional functions), an idea that goes back to Frege (see for instance Quine 1940). Furthermore, the notion of function is seen as more primitive than the notion of predicates and relations, and a function is not defined anymore as a special kind of relation. (Oppenheimer and Zalta 2011 presents some arguments against such a primitive representation of functions.)

Can someone please tell me where I can read more about their differences, comparison and the root and philosophy behind each?

Also I want to know why it is claimed to be more elegant to have functions as primitive objects here?